# Wordpress category of CPT pagination page 2 ERROR

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-taxonomy, theme-development

I got problem of my pagination in category pages >>
I made a category taxonomy for my CPT and when I add posts and posts goes to page 2 .. the page 2 got a ERROR not found

```php
<?php
// ==== Query Dynamic Options ====//

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args  = array(
    'post_type'      => 'portfolio',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'orderby'        => 'ID',
    'taxonomies'     => 'portfolio-categories',

);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

if you wanna see more code that will helps u to help me ask it for me I will capture it

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `taxonomies`  isn't a query argument.  What is the page 2 url you end up with?

Comment: https://elma.test/?portfolio-categories=%D8%B2%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%AC&paged=2
@HowardE

Comment: and I fitch the taxonomies  with 'tax_query' too @HowardE